# Add trusted sites to windows registry for all users

Tags: windows, vbscript

I want to add trusted web sites to the windows registry for all users using a VBScript. I currently have a script with me and its given below. I'm neither a Windows guy nor a Visual Basic guy, so I have absolutely no idea whether the script would run or not and would it meet my needs or not. Could someone please explain the script and check whether would it run as expected.

```
On Error Resume Next

Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & strComputer & _
  "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" _
  & "ZoneMap\EscDomains\google.com"

objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" _
  & "ZoneMap\EscDomains\google.com\www"

objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath

strValueName = "https"
dwValue = 2

objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" _
  & "ZoneMap\Domains\google.com"

objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" _
  & "ZoneMap\Domains\google.com\www"

objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath

strValueName = "https"
dwValue = 2

objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" _
  & "ZoneMap\EscDomains\hotmail.com"

objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath

strValueName = "https"
dwValue = 1

objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" _
  & "ZoneMap\Domains\hotmail.com"

objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath

strValueName = "https"
dwValue = 1

objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
```

If you feel this is an inappropiate script, please share the VBScript which you feel that would work.

Comment: Sorry for being blunt, but you're in the wrong place. Here on SO we expect you to have at least a basic understanding of the subject you're asking about. If you don't you need to work your way through a tutorial first. SO is not a replacement for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT     = &H80000000
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER     = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE    = &H80000002
Const HKEY_USERS            = &H80000003
Const HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG   = &H80000005
```

Your script is adding to current user, not all users as you said you need. Will multiple real users be logging into that machine?

The keys you need are:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\<website>.com]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\<website>.com\www]
"http"=dword:00000002
```

You could create a .reg file with above information for the websites and run it (put "`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`" at the top of that .reg file)

As has already been indicated, some quality time on Google will definitely enhance your knowledge of what the script you posted is trying to do and how to modify it. Don't hesitate to ask any specific (as opposed very general)  questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Did it help you? If so, it is customary to upvote an answer (using the up arrow) and accept it (using the check mark next to it) if it helps you with your question.

Comment: Just one more doubt. So if i want to add the sites for all its users, i have to change HKEY_CURRENT_USER to HKEY_USERS ????

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. Since this is the registry, I'd proceed carefully. Best option is to try this on a virtual machine you can delete. Try one registry entry at a time. Have the registry editor open at all times to check the entry is going into the right place; use a unique URL (a junk, non-real URL) so you can easily search the registry for it after creating the entries. Check in IE that entries appear in security tab's trusted sites list. Finally, check by logging in as other users on the same machine. Code and debug with one address before putting in a bunch of them. Good luck.